# Prove that $a_{1}a_{2} +a_{2} a_{3} +a_{3} a_{1} \leq 2$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $a_{1}a_{2}  +a_{2} a_{3} +a_{3} a_{1} \leq 2$ for $a_{1} , a_{2}, a_{3}$∈[0,∞) that satisfy $a_{1} ^{3} +a_{2} ^{3}+a_{1} ^{3}=\frac{3}{2}$

I tried using the formula $a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)[a^2+b^2+c^2−ab−bc−ac]+3abc$ but failed.

Comment: Please say what you have tried. Just uploading a problem is not the right way.

Answer (score 4):

Use GM $\leq$ AM, with $a_{k}, a_{j}$ and $1$ in the following way

$
a_{1}a_{2} + a_{2}a_{3} + a_{1}a_{3} \leq \frac{a_{1}^{3}+a_{2}^{3}+1^{3}}{3}+\frac{a_{2}^{3}+a_{3}^{3}+1^{3}}{3}+\frac{a_{1}^{3}+a_{3}^{3}+1^{3}}{3} = 1+\frac{2\left(a_{1}^{3}+a_{2}^{3}+a_{3}^{3}\right)}{3} = 2
$